# In ΔABC, BC=2CA; the internal bisector of angle C meets AB at X and AA' is a median. If A'X meets CA produced at Z prove that A is the midpoint of CZ.

Tags: geometry

> In ΔABC, BC=2CA; the internal bisector of angle C meets AB at X and AA' is a median. If A'X meets CA produced at Z prove that A is the midpoint of CZ. If also AA', CX intersect at O and BO cuts at CA at Y, prove that Y is a point of trisection of CA.

[image]

$\frac {AC}{BC} = \frac{AX}{XB} = \frac{1}{2}$

$BA'=CA'=AC=\frac {BC}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

[image: Fig-1 and Fig-2]

This is not a very difficult problem to solve, if you know the four laws of congruence and Menelaus theorem. I will give you some hints in the form of steps for you to carry out. Let us see whether you can find the solution yourself using these guidelines.

For the first part, prove that the two triangles $AXC$ and $CXA_1$ are congruent in $\mathrm{Fig. 1}$. Then, you have to prove the two triangles $AZX$ and $XBA_1$ are congruent. That is all you have to do to show that $A$ is the midpoint of $CZ$.

For the second part, you have to use some of the things you have proved in the first part. You have to begin by proving $AO=OA_1$. For this, you have to consider the isosceles triangle $CAA_1$ in $\mathrm{Fig. 2}$. Thereafter, apply Menelaus theorem to the triangle $CAA_1$ and the intersecting line $BOY$ to obtain the desired result, i.e. $Y$ is a point of trisection of $CA$.

The methods described above are not the only way to solve this problem. If you know a better way, you are welcome to use your very own methods to find the answers.